# First order PDE with two conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, initial-value-problems, linear-pde

I am asked to solve this IVP

$$
\begin{cases}
u_x+2xu_t=0\\
u(x,0)=0\\
u(0,t)=t, \qquad t\geq 0
\end{cases}
$$

I already have found the general solution, that is:

$$\frac{1}{dx}=\frac{2x}{dt}=\frac{0}{du} $$

skipping some computations, yields

$$u(x,t)=\Phi(x^2-t)$$

At this point, I started to use separately the conditions:

$$
\begin{cases}
u(x,0)=\Phi(x^2)=0 \quad\rightarrow\quad \zeta_1:=x^2 \quad\rightarrow\quad \zeta_1 - x^2=0\\
u(0,t)=\Phi(-t)=t \quad\rightarrow\quad \zeta_1:=-t \quad\rightarrow\quad t=-\zeta_1
\end{cases}
$$

How could I end in order to solve it? Can anyone help me to combine the two conditions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure about the initial value $u(x,0)=0$ and the boundary value $u(0,t)=t$? They seem to contradict each other. If the initial value is $u(x,0)=-x^2$ the solution is given by $u(x,t)=t-x^2$. Note that we can conclude from the boundary condition: $u(0,t)=\Phi(-t)=t \implies \Phi(t)=-t$.

Comment: On YouTube I found someone that solved the problem via Laplace Transform obtaining $u(x,t)=(t-x^2)\cdot H(t-x^2)$. Even by neglecting the Heaviside function, the initial condition does not yield. That's why I wanted to solve it by characteristics before....

Comment: I cannot understand why some people down voted the question from Clyde A.Jansen. The wording is correct and the effort is obviously shown since the general solution of the PDE was found. In order to compensate the undeserved down votes, I up vote.

Comment: Thanks, JJacquelin. You are among the rare people without prejudice. :) I do owe you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with $\quad u(x,t)=\Phi(x^2-t)$

Let $\quad X=x^2-t$

Conditions :

$$\begin{cases}
u(x,0)=0= \Phi(x^2) \quad\implies\quad \Phi(X)=0\\
u(0,t)=t= \Phi(-t),\quad t\geq 0 \quad\implies\quad \Phi(X)=-X,\quad X\leq 0
\end{cases}$$

Graphical representation of the function $\Phi(X)$ :

[image]

Obviously, the analytical form of the function $\Phi(X)$ is :
$$\Phi(X)=-X\:\text{H}(-X)$$
H is the Heaviside step function.

Putting this function into the general solution $\quad u(x,t)=\Phi(x^2-t)\quad$ leads to :

$$ u(x,t)=-(x^2-t)\:\text{H}\big(-(-x^2-t)\big)$$
$$ u(x,t)=(t-x^2)\:\text{H}\big(t-x^2\big)$$

Final checking :

For $t<x^2$ the solution of the PDE is trivial : $u=0$.

For $t>x^2$ the solution $\quad u=-x^2+t\quad$ satisfies the PDE because $u_x=-2x\Phi'$ and $u_t=\Phi'$ hence $u_x+2xu_t=0$.

At $t=0 \quad\to\quad H(-x^2)=0 \quad\to\quad u(x,0)=0\:\:$ which satisfies the boundary condition.

At $x=0 \quad\to\quad H(t)=1 \quad\to\quad u(0,t)=-0+t=t\:\:$ which satisfies the boundary condition.

Comment: I'm agreeing with you that there's something strange.... So let me link the resource I found (I hope that pasting the video link does not violate any rule): 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kvEqw6tUtgM

Comment: I agree with the solution thanks to the Laplace transform. Of course, as it happen in all these cases with the Heaviside function, on the "wavefront" at $(x^2=t)$ the partial differentials $u_x$ and $u_y$ are not strictly defined. But the PDE is satisfied on left and on right from the wave front.

Comment: I re-edited my main answer in order to make more rigorous the  treatment of the boundary conditions.

Comment: Thanks JJacquelin. I copied your useful main answer.